# Why route method not found 'change_password_admin_user' using ActiveAdmin / Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

Can't understand how this method isn't found?

```
undefined method `change_password_admin_user' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::ActionItems:0x007ff1cad9d848>
```

Output of my `rake routes`

```
change_password_admin_user GET /admin/users/:id/change_password(.:format) /users#change_password
```

Comment: how are you calling it?

Comment: You probably want `change_password_admin_user_path` or `change_password_admin_user_url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears that you don't have used the suffix in the method call. Two methods are generated by the route that you pasted in in your question:

```
change_password_admin_user_path
```

Which return a path relative to the domain, and the other version which includes the host of your site:

```
change_password_admin_user_url
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple that a rookie like me could over look.  Thanks again!